# Strange behavior on newest question page when refreshing page

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, newest-questions

I have face strange behavior on newest question list page. I am using Comodo Dragon as web browser (a Google Chrome variant).

When I visiting page on : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/java and waiting about a minute, I got new question notification like below:

[image: init]

And, when I click the notification, as usual I got the new  question fetched. Then, I try to press refresh button (even I also press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>F5</kbd>). The strange behavior happen here. The question list are still the same as above picture, is this problem on my browser or anyone faced this problem too?

Okay

Comment: Sounds like everyone had this problem today. It seems now the feature has been fixed. Thanks. ;)